# JavaScript function not running?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Okay, so me and my friend are rather new to programming, we have some experience, but not too much, and I'm sure we're just making a stupid mistake here.  We are attempting to make a "Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock" game with HTML and JavaScript.  Here's our code:

```
<td>
        <p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;">Choose...</p>
            <form name="userInput"  action="javascript:getUserChoice">
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_rock" value="rock">Rock</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_paper" value="paper">Paper</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_scissors" value="scissors">Scissors</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_lizard" value="lizard">Lizard</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_spock" value="spock">Spock</input> </br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
            </form>
    </td>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    var userChoice = getUserChoice();

    function getUserChoice(userChoice)
    {

        if (document.userInput.getElementById('userChoice_rock').checked)
        {
        userChoice = "rock";
        }

        else if (document.userInput.getElementById('userChoice_paper').checked)
        {
        userChoice = "paper"
        }

        else if (document.userInput.getElementById('userChoice_scissors').checked)
        {
        userChoice = "scissors"
        }

        else if (document.userInput.getElementById('userChoice_lizard').checked)
        {
        userChoice = "lizard"
        }
        else if (document.userInput.getElementById('userChoice_spock').checked)
        {
        userChoice = "spock"
        }
}       

    </script>
```

I'm sure we're making an obvious mistake here.  I've been using Chrome developer tools (Inspect Element) to find various syntax errors and such.  That's probably not very professional of me, but it's worth a shot.  Do you see any errors?  We do know how to write a script for the computer choice and comparisons as we have experience with that.  Our only issue is defining the user choice.  And it'd be really great if anyone here could help me out with this!

Comment: So what is the question? What does not work? Using Chrome developer tools is absolutely professional, but what was the result of using it? Actually I would recommend that you guys delete this question for now, complete some nice and very basic Javascript tutorials, and when you feel you are getting it, try writing this game again. We cannot really help at this stage, because this site is not here to tutor. I wish you best luck.

Comment: Why is `getUserChoice` asking for an argument when you don't use it?

Comment: instead of `userChoice = "rock";` use `return "rock";` and then apply those same changes to all of your other ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your global var `userChoice` has the same name as the function's argument.  The function `getUserChoice` over writes it's parameters value with the values set in the conditionals.  Then it does nothing with it; once you leave the function's scope, it's lost.

If you want the function to operate on the global variable, don't give the function a parameter with the same name.

The second problem is that you assign the global varible `userChoice` the return value of your function, and since it doesn't return anything, it actually over writes the value with undefined.  So even if you did the above, it still wouldn't work.

Fourth `document.userInput` isn't defined.  You need to query for it, e.g. `document.getElementById('userInput')`.

All in all, a better solution would be to do this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var userChoice;

            var setUserChoice = function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var choices = event.target.userChoice;

                for (var i =0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                    if (choices[i].checked) {
                        userChoice = choices[i].value;
                    }
                }

                event.target.choice.value = userChoice;
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                var form = document.getElementById('userInput');
                form.addEventListener('submit', setUserChoice, false);
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="userInput">
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_rock" value="rock">Rock</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_paper" value="paper">Paper</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_scissors"value="scissors">Scissors</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_lizard" value="lizard">Lizard</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_spock" value="spock">Spock</input> </br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enter" /></br>
                <output name="choice"></output>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After that you are calling the `getUserChoice` method ant the beginning even after the user make his real choice you have to attach this function to the clic event something like this:

```
var submit_button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
submit_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    getUserChoice();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, 2 things, first i needed to put (), without my firefox dont call the function

```
<form name="userInput"  action="javascript:getUserChoice()">
```

second, you need to change:

```
if (document.userInput.getElementById('userChoice_rock').checked)
```

to

```
if (document.getElementById('userChoice_rock').checked)
```

since `userInput` is not a member of `document`

if you would now put

```
alert(userChoice);
```

at the end of the function, you will get the userChoice on clicking the submit button