# How to compare user input with attribute values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this and I want to compare in a loop the attribute values of name with user entered input stored in variable "user". How can I do this?

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="two">
<input type="radio" name="three">
<input type="radio" name="four">
<input type="radio" name="five">
<input type="radio" name="six">
</form>
```

Comment: There's `getElementsByName(user)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OnChange event handler for radio button (INPUT type="radio") doesn't work as one value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838648/onchange-event-handler-for-radio-button-input-type-radio-doesnt-work-as-one)

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839323/405096) answer for an example of how to loop through radio buttons in native javascript, quoted here for convenience:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var userChoice;

            var setUserChoice = function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var choices = event.target.userChoice;

                for (var i =0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                    if (choices[i].checked) {
                        userChoice = choices[i].value;
                    }
                }

                event.target.choice.value = userChoice;
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                var form = document.getElementById('userInput');
                form.addEventListener('submit', setUserChoice, false);
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="userInput">
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_rock" value="rock">Rock</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_paper" value="paper">Paper</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_scissors"value="scissors">Scissors</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_lizard" value="lizard">Lizard</input> </br>
                <input type="radio" name="userChoice" id="userChoice_spock" value="spock">Spock</input> </br>
                <input type="submit" value="Enter" /></br>
                <output name="choice"></output>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare tha values like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wd8p/

**HTML**

```
<form action="demo.html" id="myForm">
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="two">
        <input type="radio" name="three">
        <input type="radio" name="four">
        <input type="radio" name="five">
        <input type="radio" name="six">
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    var user = "three"; //default value: depends on youur code..

    //Loop through each radio element of the DOM
    $("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
        //Compare values of the "name" attribute and the user var
        if (user == $(this).attr("name")){
            alert("Same: " + $(this).attr("name"));
        }else{
            alert("Different: " + $(this).attr("name"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 document.getElementsByName(user)[0]
```